# Who are those paying the price in the Ukrainian crisis?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, ukraine

I don't know what is going to happen in the [Ukrainian crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021%E2%80%932022_Russo-Ukrainian_crisis), but I noticed that since the beginning of the cold war when the big guys stir and jostle the small guys in between get squeezed or crushed. So I wondered who are this time those who are going to pay the price of the tension.

For example I noticed that small countries are being heavily militarised even if they are far from the actual contested areas. On one side Poland and the Baltic Republics, on the other Belarus, even if Belarus is more than 500 Kilometres from the Donetsk and Luhansk areas. But apart this point I don't know enough about what is happening there.

I know that a full answer to this question is not possible. As of now we hear too much noise and not enough details. But partial answers mentioning some of those who will get the squeeze are already something more that what we are being told currently.

**Update:**

I see that several people flagged to close this question on the ground that it is looking for predictions about the future. But actually that is not what I was asking for. To make it more clear I'll make an example:
According to an article by the TASS among the objective of the [military drill of the joint Belarusian and Russian forces in Belarus](https://tass.com/russia/1402131) are:

> strikes against the area occupied by notional illegal armed gangs

> countering terrorism and protecting the interests of the Union State

I don't know whether this is really connected to the Ukainian crisis, but according to the US administration and the western media it is. Trouble is that at the same time in Belarus there are strong protests against [Lukashenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Lukashenko) and the Belarusian government. I don't think that in such context Belarusian citizens are so happy to have Russian troops training for countering terrorism nearby. This is something actual.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. E.g. the Luhansk and Donetsk breakaway regions ordered a general mobilization to deal with an allegedly imminent Ukraine invasion, would you say the people mobilized are "paying the price"? Some of the women and children in both regions were evacuated to Russia, would you say the Russian regions that have to accommodate them are paying the price?

Comment: The situation in Belarus has not much to do with Ukraine crysis, even there is some indirect relation.

Comment: The question isn't clear but this appears to be looking for predictions about the future, specifically what the effect will be on the Baltic states and other small nations. Such predictions are almost impossible to make, as we don't know if there will be a war, now large it will be, or what course it will take, and therefore it's considered off-topic.

Comment: @convert I am not the one linking the military exercises in Belarus to the Ukrainian crisis, but the US administration.

Comment: @Allure and also Stuart F It seems you are far from the area of the crisis and that both of you don't know much more than I do on the situation on the ground. In such cases you don't have to provide an answer, leave it to those who have a more direct experience.

Comment: Ukraine and Belarus share a border so there is more to it then the 500KM distance that you are claiming

Comment: @JoeW Please look at a map and the distance from the contested area, Donetsk and Luhansk. If you instead mean that the US meant an invasion of the whole of Ukraine, in this case 200.000 soldiers are not enough look at the country size and population size.

Comment: I don't think it is fair to make a claim that there is a 500KM distance when talking about two countries that border each other or make assumptions that those 200,000 soldiers are all that are involved. When you are in a friendly country traveling 500KM isn't that much of a challenge.

Comment: @JoeW When people start mixing up the small details as third class lawyers do I assume they don't really want to carry on a discussion.

Comment: The "small" detail that the two countries in question share a border? The "small" detail that the troops in one of the countries are free to move around and get closer? The "small" detail that those are not the only troops in question? The "small" detail that this is not the only area where Russia appears to be gathering troops for an invasion? If Russia is planning an invasion of Ukraine it will be to their advantage to attack from multiple sides and it won't matter how far those troops are from the conflict area you are referring to.

Comment: @JoeW Of course. Not only the Americans know that Russia is going to invade Ukraine, they also know their battle plan. First of all they will occupy the area contaminated by the Chernobyl accident because they like the radiations. The green men will become glowing green.

Comment: You consider them small details and others consider them critical details, personally I consider it an important fact that the two countries border each other and it is small detail about how far troops are away from an area of conflict. If Russia is going to use those troops to invade they won't be going to the conflict area but instead to parts of the country that are much much closer.

Comment: It now appears those troops (or others in Belarus) are being used to attack Ukraine. https://thehill.com/policy/international/595621-ukrainian-state-border-services-says-troops-attacked-from-belarus

Comment: @JoeW That's not correct. Russians fired missiles to Kiev, but then they invaded other cities. Furthermore even though you keep turning a blind eye to it Russian troops did not enter the area contaminated by the Chernobyl accident. You cannot go from Belarus to Kiev without going through the entire area.

Comment: I guess you can continue to make excuses for Russia by claiming the troops in some areas are not involved in this. First you claim the issue is the distance and now you are claiming the issue is Chernobyl? What will the issue be preventing those troops from doing anything next?

Comment: @JoeW "I guess you can continue to make excuses for Russia"  I guess you are dishonest by claiming that who does not agree with your opinion is a supporter of another side. Usual disgusting propaganda tactics. World is not just black and white, as you probably know.

Comment: @JoeW "I guess you can continue to make excuses for Russia " BTW You are making a lot more excuses than me by denying the repression of the rebellions in Belarus.

Comment: Rebellions is your new excuse? I am just pointing out that moving troops into Belarus when they border Ukraine and are near the Ukraine capital is a serious concern and as they have troops along large sections of the Ukraine border they should not be written off as a non threat. As you even admitted they are attacking Ukraine from Belarus right now which is only possible due to them having troops in the country. And I wonder what your next excuse will be for the troops in Belarus as we appear to be up to 3 now and the stated reason was joint exercises.

Comment: Russia jus seized Chernobyl so I don't think that was a concern for them. https://www.axios.com/ukraine-zelensky-chernobyl-nuclear-power-plant-2f549a11-6bc3-466c-bf30-23fafb41b3a3.html

Answer (score 4):

The people most affected by the Ukrainian crisis are obviously the Ukrainians - I use this term to describe all people living on the territory of what was technically Ukraine before the [government overthrow of 2013-14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolution_of_Dignity). This obviously includes [more than 10,000 killed and about 25,000 wounded](https://www.cfr.org/global-conflict-tracker/conflict/conflict-ukraine).

*Ukrainians in Donetsk and Luhansk regions*
Note that most of these Ukrainians are native Russian speakers and would be frequently referred to as "Russians" in colloquial parlance and viewed as enemies of Ukraine. Yet, as of 2013 they held Ukrainian citizenship and they should be treated as such from the point of view of Ukraine being a democratic state, aiming for EU and NATO membership.

Some of them are among the above mentioned casualties - either because they joined (or had to join) the fighting against the Ukrainian forces, or simply because they became accidental casualties, aka "collateral damage". Others were displaced from the war region or had their houses/apartments destroyed during the fighting. Many lost their livelihood due to the economic disruption when the eastern regions were cut from the Ukraine, whereas the government in Kyiv essentially stopped providing services to them (such as paying pensions or disability benefits, etc.) Their freedom of movement was also severely limited by the war - both within Ukraine, as well as in terms of traveling abroad - since logistically it can be done only via Russia, and obtaining travel documents requires assistance of the Ukrainian authorities in Kyiv. It is therefore not surprising that many of the original inhabitants of these regions have relocated to Russia, some obtaining Russian citizenship.

In terms of political freedoms - it is not clear whether these are fully assured in the self-proclaimed Donetsk and Luihansk republics. For those who left to Russia it obviously poses less problems (all the criticism of Russia notwithstanding, Russians today enjoy pretty much the same political freedoms as people living in western Europe or US - light years from what it was during the Soviet times). Finally, they do not suffer from discrimination due to their Russian background (the first Ukrainian government heavily relied on the nationalist forces, promulgating laws that diminished the rights of minorities - known as [*Ukrainization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainization)).

*Ukrainians in western Ukraine*
Again, many of the casualties cited in the beginning are those among the soldiers who either joined fighting as volunteers or were conscripted to the Ukrainian army. Western Ukrainians were also had their freedom of movement in the country limited by the war, and some were probably cut from their families in the east. On the other hand, the EU and the US have eased the visa procedures for Ukrainians, improving the international mobility. The economic consequences of the war were partially offset by the help of the IMF, US and EU.

*Inhabitants of Crimea*
Apart from the military personnel at the Russian naval base, these were Ukrainian citizens pre-2013/14, and were granted Russian citizenship upon the Russian annexation of Crimea. There was almost no fighting in these region, but the restrictions on the mobility are pretty much the same as for the Eastern Ukrainians. Russia has poured massive funding in improving the infrastructure of these region and encouraged Russian tourism in Crimea - an important part of the local economy.

*Former Soviet countries adjacent to Ukraine or Russia (Lithuania, Latvia, Estonia, Poland, etc.)*
Given the historical tensions between these countries have with Russia, the main effect of the conflict was political - strengthening the anti-Russian sentiment... but also provoking pro-Russian reaction (notably in Poland and Hungary). There have been much investment into the military as well as with the increase of the NATO presence. On the other hand, the disruption of the economic chains, as well as the volatility of the price of the gas passing through the Ukraine, are the negatives.

*Western Europe*
The most felt effects were the volatility of the gas prices, as  well as the economic consequences of the sanctions. E.g., French farmers have been negatively affected by reduced access to the Russian market. [The refusal of France to deliver to Russia the Mistral ships](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affaire_des_Mistral) that were constructed at the Saint-Nazaire shipyard had serious consequences for the latter, resulting in its bankruptcy and narrowly avoided takeover by a foreign investor (to avoid the loss of the strategic asset the shipyard was nationalized).

Comment: My question was more specific. I was not referring to the fighting that has been going on for years, the consequences of it we already know. I was referring to the current spike in the tension.

Comment: Note that many Russian-speaking Ukraininans do consider themselves to be Ukrainians.

Comment: @FluidCode They cannot be separated. It is the continuation of the single frozen conflict.

Comment: @VladimirF I did my best to avoid biasing the answer towards either Ukraine or Russia. People can be Russians and Ukrainians in the same time - not only due to a dual citizenship, but due to different meaining of these terms (nationality/citizenship vs. etnicity/culture).

Comment: @FluidCode I think at the moment it is too early to speak of the results of the current spike in the tensions. There are some evacuations in the east of Ukraine, and some additional Ukrainians and Russians have to do the army service.

Answer (score 0):

*I will briefly mention a few items, and will expand if I get the confirmation that I understood the OP correctly. Waiting for the comments from the OP, not for upvotes/downvotes (irrelevant to me, sorry).*

The following small guys will pay the price for the current spike in the tensions resulting from the Russia-Ukraine conflict (current sources/evidence in parentheses, references provided upon request from the Pol.SE community).

- Soldiers killed in fighting: Russians in Russia, Russian "green men" in the occupied Ukraine (DNR, LNR, Crimea), Ukrainians (Twitter).
- Families and friends of those killed and MIA: in Russia and Ukraine (Twitter, common sense).
- Entire population of Ukraine, including children, who are paying the price in higher levels of stress, associated behavioral issues, higher inflation, flight cancellation by multiple airlines, military expenditures (private communication with residents of Ukraine, Twitter).
- Entire population of Russia, who are paying the price for military expenditures [speculation], and for the side effects of the Western sanctions against the Putin's regime [/speculation] (Twitter, common sense).
- The terrorized part of the DNR/LNR population who are victims of the terror campaign (Russian mainstream media, Twitter)
- [speculation] Entire population of Europe when the war refugees start streaming over the porous Ukrainian borders into all of Europe, after Putin's regime actually invades further than in already did in 2014 (Twitter). [/speculation]